# Does @property (retain) autorelease or release objects?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode4, nsautoreleasepool, nswindowcontroller

I'm having completely unexpected timing problems with the super simple code below.  One of the variables is being autoreleased, and I have no clue why.  I'm not using autorelease, KVO, etc. It shouldn't be happening.

The `WindowController` is set as an `@property (retain)`'d of `MainController`.

In the `-dealloc` of the `MainController`, I do `self.windowController = nil;`

But, it keeps waiting until the autorelease pool is flushed to release the windowController.  I expect the WindowController's dealloc to be called as soon as `self.windowController = nil` is done.  Even if I wrap the [mainController release] in NSAutoreleasePool, it still doesn't release right away.

Why is this happening?

---

This doesn't seem like proper behavior for the @property / NSWindowController. Am I missing something?

---

Correction: It's **not** bindings.  I officially have no clue what the problem is.

Main driver:

```
[[MainController new] release];
```

MainController.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "WindowControllerSubclass.h"
@interface MainController : NSObject {
    WindowControllerSubclass *wc;
}

@property (retain) WindowControllerSubclass *wc;

@end
```

MainController.m:

```
#import "MainController.h"

@implementation MainController

@synthesize wc;

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        // This is problem here >>>  If I assign directly to wc, then it's not added to autorelease pool
        self.wc = [[WindowControllerSubclass alloc] init];
        [self.wc release]; // since it's (retain)'d
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) dealloc {
    self.wc = nil;
    NSLog(@"%@ deallocd (should be called after WC's dealloc)", [self className]);
}

@end
```

MainWindowControllerSubclass.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface WindowControllerSubclass : NSObject /* Not even NSWindowController */
@end
```

MainWindowControllerSubclass.m:

```
#import "WindowControllerSubclass.h"

@implementation WindowControllerSubclass

- (void) dealloc {
    NSLog(@"%@ deallocd", [self className]);
}

@end
```

Comment: I hope that this is a typo: `[[MainController new] release];`. If not, it's a major problem because you're immediately releasing the object that you're creating.

Comment: Can't tell for sure right now (no Mac at hand), but it is possible that property's getter is implemented as `[[wc retain] autorelease]`. It's a common pattern for getters.

Comment: @Rob. It's not a typo.  I'm doing it to test the MainController.  It needs to show the nslogs in the proper order.  That's the whole point of this simple problem example.

Comment: You can override `autorelease` method in your controller, set a breakpoint and see who and when does it.

Comment: @Eugene, your guess was right. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing strange about it, especially if your `NSWindowController` is in an autorelease pool.

An object (say `x`) is dealloc'ed when every object which owns it releases it. `Autorelease` is a deferred release, i.e. it doesn't actually release until the autorelease pool is drained.

Consider the following chain of events:

```
    B creates x
    A owns x
    A autoreleases x. // x is not released; it's put on an autorelease pool
    B releases x.     // x is not dealloced yet, because x is not released by the autorelease pool
    autorelease pool is drained. x is sent another release message. nobody owns x. x is dealloc'd.
```

That's what you're seeing.

--- Update ---

More, precisely, the mysterious usage of autorelease pool arises from your line

```
[self.wc release];
```

This uses the getter of `wc`, i.e. it calls `[self wc]`. Now, the default synthesized getter is implemented in [this portion of obj-c runtime](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-493.9/runtime/Accessors.subproj/objc-accessors.m), in particular `objc_getProperty_non_gc`. Note that your property is `(retain)`, i.e. it's `(atmomic retain)`. To guarantee atomicity, the getter `retain`s the ivar and then returns it after `autorelease`'ing it:

```
id *slot = (id*) ((char*)self + offset);
if (!atomic) return *slot;

// Atomic retain release world
spin_lock_t *slotlock = &PropertyLocks[GOODHASH(slot)];
_spin_lock(slotlock);
id value = objc_retain(*slot);
_spin_unlock(slotlock);

// for performance, we (safely) issue the autorelease OUTSIDE of the spinlock.
return objc_autoreleaseReturnValue(value);
```

That's why it's put on the autorelease pool. In any case,

```
obj.property=[[SomeClass alloc] init];
[obj.property release];
```

is a bad idea. In your case, `self.ivar` in the second line returned what you assigned in the first line, but that's not guaranteed in the case of clever, non-synthesized accessors, or in a multi-threaded environment. When you do

```
obj.property=x;
id y=obj.property;
```

`x` and `y` can be different, if `obj` does some clever caching, or if there's another thread accessing `obj` which changes `obj.property` between the two lines.  So, use a temporary variable instead:

```
SomeClass* a=[[SomeClass alloc] init];
obj.property=a;
[a release];
```

Comment: That's right, but I'm very curious to know how his window controller ended up in the autorelease pool in the first place...

Comment: It's automatically added. Each thread in a Cocoa application maintains its own stack of `NSAutoreleasePool` objects.

Comment: @Yuji autorelease is never used in my code.  No clue what it's added to the AR pool.  See code above.

Comment: The compiler and/or `NSObject`'s implementation can and do use `NSAutoreleasePool` behind the scenes. You shouldn't care, as long as everything is cleaned up when the autorelease pool is drained the next time.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `self.windowController = nil;` with `[self.windowController release];` (The former type of code, i.e. setting things to nil, is (sometimes) used in a garbage collected environment, although not in a dealloc method.)

Comment: Can you look at the code you're using to allocate the window controller and assign it to self.windowController? My guess is this: When you allocated the window controller, the retain count is 1. And when you assign it to self.windowController, the retain count becomes 2 (since the @property is set to "retain"). So when you release, the retain count gets back to 1, and therefore there is no deallocation. If I am right, you might be able to fix this problem by using "@property (assign)" instead.

Comment: It is being released fine, it's just being released in the autorelease pool.  So retain count isn't the problem here.  That's the mind-boggling thing.

Comment: Can you post the code you used to allocate the window controller and assign it to self.windowController?

Comment: Calling `self.windowController == nil` will have exactly the same result as calling `[self.windowController release]` except that the pointer will be set to nil. Both will release the object. This is not the cause of the "problem".

Comment: @Rob I "discovered" my problem. But not sure how to solve it.  Basically, the code above shows that any kind of bindings cause the controller to be placed on the auto-release stack.  How do I fix this?

Comment: Why do you need to fix it? Why do you care when the object is actually deallocated?

Comment: @Rob that's a silly question.  It's not behaving as intended, so it's a major problem.  But to put in other ways.  The item is being released AFTER the main object releases it.  When it's being released, it accesses memory that's no longer allocated (in another object) because it's not properly released.  A contains B and C. B is linked to C.  A releases C.  B is autoreleased and attempted to tell C to do something.  Except now C is released.  Take a look at the code above.

Comment: This sounds like a retain cycle. How is B linked to C? You only have two objects in your code above, not three. Please show exactly how all the objects are linked to each other.

Answer (score 0):

Your expectations are not right. This is the key idea of reference-counted memory management: `release` never guarantee deallocation; the object is only deallocated when everyone who retained it decides to release. And if somewhere it is still retained, there is no way you can force deallocation.

UPDATE:

First, property getter is implemented as `return [[wc retain] autorelease]` (see Yuji's answer).

Second, Cocoa can retain and autorelease your WindowController too. If it's not happening right now, it does not mean it won't happen when you add more code.

You should NOT make assumptions about order of deallocations, or that `autorelease` will or will not be called. You can not even assume that the pool will be drained immediately at the end of the run loop, as there may be custom run loop running.

Fix your objects so they can handle any possible deallocation sequence.

Comment: You misunderstood.  I wasn't using autorelease at any point.  I am using explicitly memory management.

Comment: Some Cocoa code did it. Your code is not the only one who retains and releases objects. That why you shouldn't make any expectations about it.

Comment: But I have no clue where the Autorelease is coming from.  Plus, that's not proper.  The item is being released AFTER the main object releases it. When it's being released, it accesses memory that's no longer allocated (in another object) because it's not properly released. A contains B and C. B is linked to C. A releases C. A is dealloc'd, and releases B and C. C is dealloc'd.  B is autoreleased (problem) and attempted to tell C to do something. Except now C is released.

Comment: It's called dangling pointer. C's `dealloc` must call B and tell that it's no longer alive. Autorelease is not a problem, it's a common operation in Cocoa; the problem is that your graph of objects can't handle some of possible dealloc scenarios.

Comment: Your example would introduce so many more problems.  Now imagine C trying to tell B that it's dead.  What if B was released before? How would C know B? How would C know if B is alive or autoreleased?  The problem is that the foundation is not behaving as intended.  Look at the simple example above.  I'm not using GC, I'm not using autorelease.  So where is the autorelease coming from?  The example is straight NSObject example.  Nothing observations etc.  And it still fails.

Comment: B must also tell C when it's dying. Whenever an object dies, you are the one responsible to make sure there are no dangling pointers to it. The foundation behaves correctly.